# Querying within other result query with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm getting a problem with a query with linq in EF.

Basically, what i'm tring to do is this, in plain SQL:

```
SELECT
    t2.*
FROM
    [SHP_Console2].[dbo].[Domain] t1
INNER JOIN
    [SHP_Console2].[dbo].[Domain] t2
    ON t2.[left] >=t1.[left] AND t2.[right]<=t1.[right]
WHERE
    t1.ID =1
```

I'm not able to do this with linq.

I'm tring this:

```
 from a in DomainRep.Where(c => c.ID == domainID).Select(c => new { c.left, c.right })
 from b in DomainRep.Where(x => x.left >= a.left && x.right <= a.right)
 select a;
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You mixed your query with anonymous types. You can't do that this way.

You also can't use `JOIN` with `>=` condition - LINQ does not support that kind of statements. However, it can be done using [alternative syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725032/greater-than-condition-in-linq-join).

```
from a in DomainRep
from b in DomainRep
where b.left >= 1.left && b.right <= a.right && a.ID = 1
select b;
```

Comment: I'm using this:

'var query = from a in unitOfWork.Get<Domain>()
                            from b in unitOfWork.Get<Domain>()
                            where b.left >= a.left && 
                            b.right <= a.right 
                            && a.ID == 1
                            select b;'

That was usefull but i'm now getting the error:

{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ptin.socialhub.shp.Modules.DomainsService.BusinessObjects.Domain] Get[Domain]()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:**    Reference: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/428c9db2-29f6-45d8-ab97-f00282397368/

```
             var query = (from a in DomainRep
             from b in DomainRep 
             where a.left >= b.left
             select b)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: I have modified my answer not to use the comparison on join.