# Non equijoins using LINQ and F#

Tags: linq, f#

I am trying to join two tables using LINQ and F# using the greater-than operator. This question is essentially the same as the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725032/greater-than-condition-in-linq-join/), but using F# instead of C#.

In my case I have two tables in an SQL Server database : **intervals** and **timelines**, both of which have fields **start_time** and **end_time**.

I need to perform a non-equijoin on these two tables, matching the start and end times in each table. I have tried doing this as follows:

```
let dc = new TypedDataContext()

let qry = 
query {
    for i in dc.intervals do 
    join t in dc.timelines on 
      (t.start_time > i.start_time && t.start_time < i.end_time)
    select (i, t)
}
```

But this predictably fails with the error :

> Invalid join relation in 'join'. Expected 'expr  expr', where 
>   is =, =?, ?= or ?=?.

Comment: Why not use two `for`s and a `where` instead of a `join`, just like the C# answer?

Comment: Thank you ildjarn. I did try something similar, but was using the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need to use a cross-join/selectmany (two fors) and a where clause.

E.g.

```
let results = query {
    for i in dc.intervals do 
    for t in dc.timelines do
    where (t.start_time > i.start_time && t.start_time < i.end_time)
    select (i, t)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. In my attempts I omitted the where clause or attempted to use it with the incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Although the [F# LINQ docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374.aspx) don't mention it, the [C# docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) (second paragraph) state that joins using the `join` keyword are always equijoins. It's probably safe to assume the behavior is consistent across the two languages. @ildjarn suggested a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890825/non-equijoins-using-linq-and-f#comment36781700_23890825).